# Second screen mirror one desktop

Tags: macos, screen, desktop, dual-screen

While I am using multiple desktops on my Mac, I would like to mirror one of these desktops on a second monitor.

This monitor would keep mirroring this desktop while I could switch between all of my desktops with my main monitor.

Any ideas on how to make this happen?

I am using an iPad as a second monitor if that might be important.

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to Ask Different!

I am assuming you are using an app such as Duet Display or Air Display for this purpose. It sounds like you are attempting to extend your desktop, rather than mirror a desktop. You will need to go to System Preferences -> Display -> Arrangement. From there, you can shoes to extend the Desktop.

Following these steps, you will be able to have one or more windows open on your iPad screen, and several desktops on your Mac screen as well.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am actually not looking for extending my desktop, I do know how this works.
I am actually looking for a solution to mirror only one desktop, while I can switch desktop on my Mac without the second monitor switching too.
I want to display on my second screen windows I won't directly see (the second monitor is displayed for someone else), so I'd like to view the same thing on my main monitor. But I also want to use my computer without the second monitor displaying it.

Comment: Oh! I understand now! Sorry. I think [this article](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20120306053841531) may help. Open Displays in System Preferences, hold down the Option key, and drag the desktop you want to mirror on top of the desktop being displayed on your iPad. This article is a little older, and I am away from my Mac right now to test it, but I would think this should solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks again for your response ! However, this solution does not work again, it offers one monitor (let's say my iPad) to only mirror one other monitor (if I had more than one principal monitors). The display menu only give one "desktop" for each monitor.. I think it can't be done natively, and I don't think there is any app that does the trick, at least I haven't found one during my research.

Comment: What app are you using? @MPikkle

Comment: I am using Air Display to connect my iPad on my Mac.

Comment: Ok. Well, I'm out of ideas. I'm sorry I couldn't help. Hopefully someone on here can figure it out. @MPikkle

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway. If I were to code this feature, any idea how I could control the display of a monitor ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't have any experience with manipulating displays on Mac. @MPikkle