# Mirror a specific desktop

Tags: macos, hdmi, desktop

I have a MacBook and I’m using the latest High Sierra with 2 displays total, my MacBook and the projector. But I only want one (or specific) desktop(s) to be mirrored to the projector an external monitor (a projector wired via HDMI). I have been looking for too long of a time not to ask here: is there any solution to only mirror a specific desktop?

I am a teacher, and I would like to have one desktop mirroring what I'm doing, while still having the liberty to navigate to other desktops and these would only be visible to me.

Basically, none of that "press option" in the Display menu in the Preferences would work, because that is effective if you work on multiple displays, not multiple desktops.

Closest thing I found was this [Second screen mirror one desktop](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/237599/second-screen-mirror-one-desktop) but no solution was found.
If there is a paid app, I'm willing to pay also. Can't continue breaking my neck (so far I've been extending my desktop so I could also see what the students see, without having to mirror desktops).

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site. How many displays total do you run? Also, what os - mission control and spaces have changed a bit in the past.

Comment: Oh sorry. I’m using the latest High Sierra. And I have 2 displays total, my MacBook and the projector. But I only want one (or specific) desktop(s) to be mirrored to the projector

Comment: I'm confused, if you have two displays total, the MacBook and a projector, simple display mirroring will work for that: System Preferences > Displays. So what **exactly** do you mean by "desktop" in your question?

Comment: @SteveChambers I have multiple desktops, or spaces, that I work on. One could be occupied by a code editor, another one by a browser, and so on. Another one could be occupied by personal notes, or another browser window for personal use. I would like to choose which desktops to mirror. As in I don't want to simply mirror my screen because I would like some desktops, or spaces, to be kept private. And extending would work here as I could choose which desktops to display, but then they're not mirrored and I need to turn to see them as well.

Comment: OK then this is an issue with terminology, which I thought possible. Unless there are utilities that modify the default behavior, mirroring a Display/Monitor results in **everything** on the mirrored display being shown on the other, hence the term "mirror." If you have two displays **PLUS** the projector (3 total displays) I believe you could keep your second display "private" EG not mirrored. What you want to do is not supported, by default, in macOS to my knowledge.